# SailsJS accessing a service from a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to create a service in sailsjs so I can access some business logic from within multiple controllers, I've stumbled upon a number of issues... The service is an 'Action log' I hope to log data about specific api calls to the database via a model.

The file structure I have:

```
api/services/actionService.js - the service to receive data from controller and log to model
api/models/Action.js - functioning model to store logged actions
api/controllers/ActionController.js - functioning controller to respond to get requests for the action model
api/controllers/AnotherController.js - I wish to access the actionService from here to input data
```

1. I am unsure how to reference the service from AnotherController.js; according to the [sails docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.10/services.md) I should be able to call `ActionService(data)` but I get an `ActionService is not defined` error. Is there something I need to do to load this dependency in the controller?
2. Am I able to reference a model from within the service? At the moment I have something like `Action.create(action)...` in the service. This hasn't caused problems yet as I haven't got passed the first issue but wondering whether I also need to load this as a dependency in the service?

I'm new to implementing services in sailsjs, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access your services in any controller using this syntax:

`<yourServicefilename>.method();`

In your case it would be `actionService.<yourMethodName>()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, got it working now. Added a method as you suggested and renamed actionService.js to ActionService.js, capitalisation issue as I was calling ActionService. Many thanks.